# How to replace two rows places in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

is there a way to replace rows places in an excel table? For example lets say row 1 has some text in 5 columns and row 2 as well. Can the text from row one be placed in row 2 and vice versa? Like row swap or something.
I would appreciate all help.

Answer (score 3):

only with the mouse and Keyboard shift key:

1. click on the row(s) number to select the complete row (*)
2. move the mouse on the edge of the selection. The cursor will look like this

[image]

3. hold the **shift key** and **left click** to move the selection to another row
4. drop the selection (no more left click). The selection will be inserted between the two rows (no overwrite)

> (* you can also select only a part of a row (B10:E10). When moving the selection to another row, be sure to stay in the same column (vertical move), where you have clicked (e.g. edge of D10 -> move vertically to D20).)

Answer (score 2):

To swap the rows manually in a worksheet:

Select the Columns from Row 2

Cut 

Select the same Columns in Row 1

Insert Cut Cells

You can find the Cut and Insert Cut Cells options by right clicking on the selected cells or pressing the Menu key.  You may also find these options in the Ribbon if you have a version of Excel that uses the ribbon.

If you want to do this in a Pivot Table, you can't.  You can move the entire row, but you can't move selected columns from that row.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow steps for Non-adjacent row/column:**
1.select the row or column you want to move
2.Click the column or row header of the first row or column in your selection then hold CTRL while you click the column / row header of other rows or columns that you want to swap the content with.
   **Follow steps for adjacent row/column:**
select the first row or column then hold SHIFT while you select the last row or column you want to swap the contents with.